# How do I determine whether or not postgres table partitioning is helpful?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, partitioning

I'm currently trying to determine whether or not postgres table partitioning is beneficial.

Background: I have a table with 40 GB and around 200 million rows. The copy, merge, and regenerate jobs in my application try to choose data from this table (often logically grouped data based on an ID), perform some work, and then again insert new rows.

How database table partitioning can be helpful in this situation is still something I don't fully understand.

Comment: Database partitioning is helpful when you have mostly read access over most of your tables.  By partitioning on different discs on different input/output channels, you increase your effective throughput.  If you work mainly with a small portion of your tables and do lots of writes, partitioning isn't as effective.  The only way you know for sure is to partition your database and measure the difference.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Using partitioning for physical data placement is a corner case in the 21st century. Usually, partitioning only improves performance for certain analytical queries; everything else will become slower. In my experience, the best part of partitioning is `DROP TABLE`. The question provides too little information for a meaningful answer, but 40GB is probably too small to make partitioning worth the effort.

Comment: *How do I determine whether or not postgres table partitioning is helpful?* Through testing. Set up a partitioned version of that table and see if the queries you wanted to be faster, are faster - you can use [`pgbench`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html). The *How can it be helpful* part is briefly described in [the overview](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-OVERVIEW).

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I have a job which basically looks at a table and perform delete and insert. I tried to run this job without partitioning and with partitioning, To my surprise this job took less time when I ran without partitioning.